# How to select which .net TargetFramework build to start?

Tags: .net

I have several projects and one which is started. It has multiple .net targets (7 and 4.8), but I would like to start (F5) one build or another. How to achieve this ?

Beginning of the project file csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-windows;net48</TargetFrameworks>
```

Comment: Look at the "Start Debugging" button on the main toolbar.  It has a dropdown button, indicated with a small downward pointing triangle.  That lets you pick the desired target framework.

Comment: @HansPassant So simple... thanks. I will accept it as answer if you post.